# Jquery PopUp Overlay Not Working within Wordpress for some reason

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have copied a very simple JQuery delayed overlay popup into Wordpress, yet it's not working at all. I believe it is something within Wordrpess, as when I move the code outside the WP generated pages (http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/themes/arthemia/overlay_test.html) it works fine, yet in WP it doesn't work at all (http://beta.ohsinsider.com/).

What am I missing here? What extra steps do I need to do to get this overlay to work with Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your include of [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) being negated by other jQuery includes

Here's what's happening on your site, in order:

- Include jQuery 1.3.1: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js
- Include jQuery Tools: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js
- Include jQuery 1.3.2: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2
- Include jQuery 1.2.3: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/plugins/thickbox/thickbox/jquery.js

So what's happening is jQuery tools is being included, but it's erased when the second jQuery include overwrites `jQuery` (and again with the last include).

Multiple versions of jQuery in the same page aren't supported, in fact this causes issues just like you're experiencing.  Include **one** version of jQuery, only once and *before* your plugins.

---

*For the updated site/new code*, here's the order:

- Include jQuery 1.3.1: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js
- Include jQuery 1.3.2: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2
- Include jQuery 1.2.3: http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/plugins/thickbox/thickbox/jquery.js
- Include jQuery Tools: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js

...so *now* the error is jQuery tools (at least that version), doesn't work on jQuery 1.2.3, it's erroring because it's incompatible.

Comment: @HollerTrain - you included jQuery *again* on line 62, this erases any plugins :)

Comment: i've updated the js tools url and it still does not work. NOTE: It works fine using the previous URL for the js tools on the test html page i created so i am thinking this is not the issue.

Comment: so are you saying i dont even need to include that jquery tools url since i am calling another jquery package on line 62?

Comment: @HollerTrain -no no...you need tools, but when you include jQuery *after* that it re-defines `jQuery` the object, erasing any plugins like `jQuery.fn.overlay`...but your client shouldn't download jQuery twice anyway, so just remove the multiple includes for it

Comment: k so i have removed the jquery call i had on line 51, leaving the line 62 to be the main jquery call, but my overlay is still not working. am i removing the wrong jquery include?

Comment: @HollerTrain - yup, include plugins *after* jQuery itself

Comment: my overlay code is called in the footer.php directly before the end of the html tag, so isn't my plugin being called after jQuery itself?

Comment: @HollerTrain - it doesn't matter when it's called, but when you include a plugin before jQuery...there's nothing to add the plugin functions to (the jQuery prototype)...and if you include jQuery before *and* after, it works fine, then jQuery the object get's overwritten, along with all the plugins on the old one.

Comment: i dont have a plugin being called before JQuery is included. all my code for my 'plugin' is in the footer many lines after the jQuery is included.

Comment: @HollerTrain - I didn't say "call", re-read my comments, I said **included**, you have an error in your `<script>` order before any code is called.  You have 1.3.1 included, then jQuery tools, then 1.3.2...that 1.3.2 include is overwriting your plugins, get rid of it.  Later you have `http://beta.ohsinsider.com/wp-content/plugins/thickbox/thickbox/jquery.js` which *again* includes jQuery.  Right now your error is that ancient 1.2.6 jQuery include from thickbox...you just need to clean up your plugins overall, include jQuery *once* (why make the user download it 3 times?)

Comment: ah ok. i just picked this site up from another programmer so i am sure there are a ton of cleaning up tasks on this site. last q: in order to get this overlay to work do i just need to use the generic jquery.js file or does it include something special that is not in the jquery.js file? TY for your help!

Comment: @HollerTrain - jquery tools is a plugin, so you'll still need to include http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js once after jQuery, preferably jQuery 1.4.4 if you're upgrading everything else (you'll want to replace thickbox with the new overlay you're using...thickbox is outdated and unsupported).

Comment: now i am only including 1.3.2 jquery, and then including the `jquery.tools.min.js` and it is still not loading. i've removed the extra jquery and thickbox includes...

Comment: @HollerTrain - You're including jQuery tools **before** jQuery...pay attention to my comments/answer, plugins have to come **after jQuery**.

Comment: now i have jquery 1.3.2 loading, then all special jquery plugins to be included and it still isn't loading correctly. thoughts?

Comment: @HollerTrain - your other plugins are still before jQuery, ui.tabs.pack.js (and the unpacked, why include both?), etc.  Use your console, you'll see the same errors I'm seeing.  Either chrome developer tools or firebug: http://getfirebug.com/